# How to define a default constructor that creates the previous object

Tags: c++, constructor

For example if I define a point object (2,3) and then use the default constructor to declare another point that would result in a point object (2,3).  Then If I were to create another point object (5,6) the default constructor would change to produce point objects (5,6).  Here is my attempt:

point.h

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

int point::previousX = 0;
int point::previousY = 0;

int defualtX = previousX;
int defualtY = previousY;

struct point{
    point(int newX = defualtX, int newY = defualtY) 
    : x(previousX = newX), y(previousY = newY){;};
    ~point(void){;};
    static int previousX;
    static int previousY;
    int x, y; 
};

#endif//POINT_H
```

There is an obvious problem in this code.  The class point has not been defined before the "previous" and "defualt" variabes; therefore, the definition of previousX and previousY will not work.  I could move the "defualt" and "previous" variables below the class definition, but then the point constructor will not work.

Comment: Move `int point::previousX = 0;` and `int point::previousY = 0;` into a separate translation unit or initialize them in the class declaration.

Comment: Terrible solution, good luck with finding bugs with this approach.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an XY-problem to me, why do you want to do this?

Comment: For no particular reason.  I just wanted to see how it could be done.  I imagine I will eventually find a use for it.

Comment: The most important thing to mention here is that default construction is a pretty bad idea, and global mutable variables are even worse, and here you've managed to make a wretched abomination that is the worst of both worlds.

Comment: I understand how global mutable variables are bad(I can fix that), but how are default constructors bad?

Comment: @dylan I think perhaps they were referring to the default *parameters* in your constructor. Using your `point` class, all of these are valid: `point()`, `point(7)`, and `point(7,42)`. In particular, it allows conversion from integers: `point p = 13;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The class point has not been defined before the "previous" and "default" variables; therefore, the definition of `previousX` and `previousY` will not work

It wouldn't work anyway, because you placed the definitions into a header file. This is incorrect: definitions must be placed in a cpp file in order to avoid doubly-defined errors during linking.

Moving the definitions into a cpp file will fix the first compile problem, but the second problem would remain: you cannot use `defaultX` and `defaultY` variables as default parameter values in the way shown in your code, because even if you could copy `previousX` and `previousY` into `defaultX` and `defaultY`, this would be a one-time copy; all calls to `point`'s constructor would use zero values, copied into `defaultX` and `defaultY` at initialization.

You can solve this by adding two constructors - with no parameters, and with a single parameter, like this:

```
point() : x(previousX), y(previousY) {}
point(int x) : x(x), y(previousY) {}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/sqcXES)

**Note:** I would strongly recommend against using a solution that relies on values of `static` variables for initialization, because it relies on the order in which constructors are executed, and breaks spectacularly in concurrent systems.

Comment: If not use the static members, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @dylan Provide access to the last point in the code that calls constructor with no arguments through some other, non-static means. This would initially complicate your system, but the result would be a lot more readable.

Comment: @dylan you can use a freestanding function, can't you? (see my answer below) although the I, too, recommend against it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass the previous values to the constructor?

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point
{
public:
Point(int newX, int newY)
{
  x = newX;
  y = newY;
}
int getX() {return x;}
int getY() {return y;}
~Point(){};
private:
int x, y; 
};

#endif//POINT_H
```

Something like `Point oldP(3,3)` and `Point newP(old.getX(),old.getY())`

Comment: because then you always have to have access to `old` which certainly doesn't hold for many projects although, what OP is trying to achieve isn't necessarily advisable

Answer (score 0):

You could defer the default initializations into free-standing functions like this:

```
namespace _detail {
  int getDefaultX();
  int getDefaultY();
}

struct point{
    static int previousX;
    static int previousY;

    point(int newX = _detail::getDefaultX(),
          int newY = _detail::getDefaultY());
    ~point();
    int x, y;
};

// in the .cpp file:


point::point(int newX, int newY)
  : x(previousX = newX), y(previousY = newY){;}
point::~point() {}

namespace _detail {
  int getDefaultX() {
    return point::previousX;
  }
  int getDefaultY() {
    return point::previousY;
  }
}
int point::previousX = 0;
int point::previousY = 0;
```

Comment: Now if you were to use the defualt constructor before creating any other points you would get a random point instead of (0,0).  Is this right?

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot to initialize `point::previousX` and `point::previousY`, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Just declare in correct order:

```
struct point{
    point(int newX = previousX, int newY = previousY) 
    : x(previousX = newX), y(previousY = newY){}

    void print() const { std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl; }

    static int previousX;
    static int previousY;
    int x, y; 
};
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/21IzLe)